# 500 после слияния вопросов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, слияние-вопросов

После слияния вопросов / After merging questions:

- [Разница между различными способами инициализации переменной](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/621278/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9)
- [В чем преимущество разных вариантов инициализации и в чем особенность инициализа](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/397115/178988)

Первая ссылка ведёт на страницу ошибки / First link shows error page.

Думаю, должен быть редирект / Redirect should've been there.

Comment: там не 404, там 500 и исключение

Comment: @PashaPash, да, поправил описание бага.

Comment: [Даёшь 40000!](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4685/500-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2#comment16587_4685)

Comment: @alexolut ссылка ведёт на этот же комментарий. В чем прикол?

Comment: @NickVolynkin [петля времени замкнулась!](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4686/176217)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а расскажешь, что там пошло не так?

Comment: @Qwertiy На сколько я могу видеть, имела места быть ошибка обработки коротких адресов вопросов.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, полная ссылка на комментарий тоже не работала, кажется.